# :active state is not working while scrolling but working on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with [my website](http://doktor.hekko24.pl)

Menu items has :active and :focus states

```
.main_menu li a:focus, .main_menu li a:active {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #af5807;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
}
```

But when i scroll the page that css is just not working.

Comment: when you scroll, the link is not active or focused, the scroll bar is

Comment: The active state is only toggled the moment when the link is clicked, so it will not work when you are also scrolling through the page. You might want to use `:focus` instead